# JS push notifications not working when trying to send notification via cURL php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, push-notification

I am working on a project and trying to implement js push notifications. Everything from JS side works fine but when I try to push a new message via php cURL I am always getting and errors..

My php code is:

```
function send_notification(){
$endpoint = 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABls3J_jBF5pHjifhEDfQ4RjKnyZV_8S_00SbgiDdx5JeekFyv3UbOTfZzzldtVxP0VH0h9N540FNwJcSLBtBSL9tDazf4mXDYCE970zIo4yrZZox1XWGW7AAJdSVEUavGwXgKrZoJV-mNokJxN44nKcG_NwTqq_3lt3-D6aBI6lwYILws';//this is endpoint returned from mozzilla when user subscribes

$publicVapidKey = 'BOzdJ4aWDSZPeDcUZmapdwN5wcrZkOzzS238W0djUC7LJQKV1dK35WPFHDpbIGWm1J4fB-ppeWRQyT2IfC_7n-s';//this is my app VAPID key

$auth = 'z1e1eNqv658TwuXgI3P0uA';//this is auth returned from mozzilla when user subscribes

$p256dh = 'BFKKT2zbWMnrAgAUiR3Yg8RfTs6XxhvRnV80dT9aioplrsg3FldZ0kUV_gBkw6PWG9Asm4y4b-UNW9WuF5FTouU';/this is p256dh returned from mozzilla when user subscribes
$data = [
'title' => 'Your Notification Title',
'body' => 'Your Notification Body',
];

$options = [
CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$auth.'',
    'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$publicVapidKey.'',
],
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
echo 'Response: ' . $response;
}

curl_close($ch);

}
```

the response from above request is "InvalidToken":

```
Response: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"InvalidToken","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}
```

I tried to replace 'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$publicVapidKey.'', with:
'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$p256dh.'',
but than the error is "VAPID public key mismatch":
Response: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"VAPID public key mismatch","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}

obviously it has to be 'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$publicVapidKey.'',
but why it says "InvalidToken" for correct Vapid key and credentials?

And my second question is:
Where /when is p256dh key used that comes from mozilla on user subscribtion ?

Thank you guys in advance for your time and eventual help !

Comment: refer to docs and check the auth page to check the proper way to do the authentication with API, also try to run the curl request via terminal and see

Comment: "refer to docs" - I lost 3 days reading and could not find official docs with cURLS params expected.. Thanks, anyway!